# passing functions and scope vars to directive in an object

Tags: angularjs, syntax, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive which looks like this:

on parent html:

```
      <cl-sort-n-reverse flip-reverse="flipReverse()" set-key="setKey(key)" sort-key="sortKey"          rev="reverse" key="body" title="Content"></cl-sort-n-reverse>
```

in directive js:

```
.directive('clSortNReverse', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            innerKey : '@key',
            title : '@title',
            inReverse: '=rev',
            sortKey:'=',
            flipReverse:'&',
            setKey:'&'

        },
        transclude :true,
        templateUrl:'../devhtml/common/sortNReverse.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
});
```

in template:

```
   <span>
      <div class="btn" ng-if="sortKey!=innerKey" data-ng-click="setKey({key:innerKey});">
        {{title}}
     </div>
     <div class="btn" ng-if="sortKey==innerKey" data-ng-click="flipReverse();">
        <b>{{title}}</b>
        <i ng-if="inReverse===true" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
        <i ng-show="inReverse===false" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
</span>
```

I would really like to be able to insert both functions ans scope level vars like sortKey and reverse to attribute inside one object I can declare in my controller. the answers I found here regarding adding objects to directive attributes all dealt with a simpler case in which the objects encapsulates only simple string or numbers. I'm stumped at how to define that options objects to include $scope level stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

In your controller:

```
$scope.sortReverseConfig = {
  flipReverse: function() {...},
  setKey: function(key) {...},
  sortKey: '',
  innerKey: $scope.body,
  inReverse: $scope.reverse,
  title: $scope.content
}
```

In your html:

```
<cl-sort-n-reverse config="sortReverseConfig"></cl-sort-n-reverse>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('clSortNReverse', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
          config: '='
        },
        transclude :true,
        templateUrl:'../devhtml/common/sortNReverse.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
});
```

Directive template:

```
<span>
  <div class="btn" ng-if="config.sortKey != config.innerKey" data-ng-click="config.setKey({key:config.innerKey});">
    {{config.title}}
  </div>
  <div class="btn" ng-if="config.sortKey == config.innerKey" data-ng-click="config.flipReverse();">
     <b>{{config.title}}</b>
     <i ng-if="config.inReverse === true" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
     <i ng-show="config.inReverse === false" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Will try that and let you know soon, just one question: isn't it a problem that we are binding functions with '=' and not '&'?

Comment: You are only binding the object, the functions should be parsed correctly.

Comment: for some reason I get the initial value of $scope.reverse for example, but it is not bound - i.e. inReverse is not refreshed when $scope.reverse is

Comment: I'm afraid it won't bound, usually when you pass an object to a directive it's a configuration object that doesn't have two way databinding. What you could do is where you do ngModel="reverse" do ngModel="sortReverseConfig.inReverse" that way they will both share the same object property.

Comment: this all was extremely helpful. so I settled eventually for setting the functions in the object, like you proposed, while leaving the variables I want to bind in separate attributes